# SPQARQL ordering by year

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, semantic-web

Using the following https://dbpedia.org/page/Woody_Allen
I have to list all the movies Woody Allen directed from oldest to newest using SPARQL and I have no idea how to make the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBpedia does not seem to have release dates for movies extracted comprehensively.  You might consider a SPARQL query against Wikidata instead.  You could start from something like [this](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Fmovie%20%28MIN%28YEAR%28%3Fdate%29%29%20AS%20%3Fyear%29%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fmovie%20wdt%3AP57%20wd%3AQ25089%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP577%20%3Fdate.%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fmovie%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fyear):

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

SELECT ?movie (MIN(YEAR(?date)) AS ?year)
WHERE {
  ?movie wdt:P57 wd:Q25089;
         wdt:P577 ?date.
}
GROUP BY ?movie
ORDER BY ?year
```

Comment: yeah exactly my issue I couldn't find any release dates on the dbpedia.The closest I go here for example on this movie
https://dbpedia.org/page/Scoop_(2006_film)
You've got  dbc:2006_films and then take the year out using substring